# How to reduce 1xn dimensional list to 1 dimensional list

Tags: python, data-manipulation

When I want to transpose a column-like numpy array, like,

```
a = array([[1],
     [2],
     [3]])
```

to a row-like numpy array, which I expected is like,

```
b = array([1,2,3])
```

But when I transpose a, I just get a 1x3 dimensional array,

```
>>> a.transpose()
>>> array([[1,2,3]])
```

I don't know how to fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using `numpy`, `numpy.transpose` doesn't change the number of dimensions of an array; `a` remains to be a 2d array if it's initially 2d array, you need to flatten it to reduce it from `2d` to `1d`:

```
import numpy as np
a = [[1],
     [2],
     [3]]

np.ravel(a)
#array([1, 2, 3])

np.squeeze(a)
#array([1, 2, 3])

np.array(a)[:,0]
# array([1, 2, 3])
```

Comment: @randomir OP said *transpose*, sounds like a numpy term.

Comment: @randomir Sure. I am not certain about it when I say *sounds like*. -

Comment: @ I'm sorry that the question is not claimed clearly, but yes, I'm just talking about a numpy array. All your provided methods are feasible while I just use a.flatten() to fix this problem up.

Answer (score 0):

```
a = [[1],
     [2],
     [3]]
b=[i for sl in a for i in sl]
print(b)
```

---

**output**

```
[1, 2, 3]
```

---

**explanation**
Using [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions)

```
[
i             #Take as a member of the final list
for sl in a   #iterate over all sublists in a
for i in sl   #iterate over each i in sublist
]
```

---

**UPDATE**

*OR* you can do, (but I would suggest the list comprehension as it does everything inline with no overhead of function calls)

```
b=transposed_list[0]
```

Comment: I get that. But I'm sorry that I didn't make it clear that my data type is numpy array actually. So maybe a numpy method is more effective. Anyway, your answer is valuable.